# rotate graph of function by 180

Tags: geometry, functions, graphing-functions

suppose that we have graph of  function

$$f(x)=1+x\cos(x)$$

and we should rotate  it by $180$ degree,question is what is  a function which describe new graph?answer is $$f(x)=x\cos(x)-1$$but i can't understand why it is so?as i know rotation by $180$ is equal to  instead of $x$,put  $-x$ is not it?in this case we will have
$f(x)=1-x\cos(x)$ or we  should change  y ordinate?i mean  when $x=0$,then $y=1$,so we should change sign in  $y$ intersection?please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate $f(x)$ by 180 degrees about the origin, you need to mirror it horizontally ($f(-x)$) and also vertically ($-f(x)$). In your case,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
-f(-x) &=& -(1+(-x)\cos(-x)) \\
&=& -(1 - x\cos(-x)) \\
&=& -1 + x\cos(-x) \\
&=& -1 + x\cos(x). \end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: in case  if we  rotate it  around y  axes,then simply only change sign in x right?

Comment: @dato: You wouldn't ordinarily think of that as a rotation, but instead a reflection, so you would be looking for $f(-x)$ -- it's only a "rotation" if you imagine your graph sitting in 3-space, and rotating the graph "out of the page" around the $y$-axis. This will make a lot more sense if you try graphing a few of them, even online or on your calculator. If you do a few by hand, though, eventually it shouldn't be confusing at all.

Comment: good night  @Eric Tressler thanks a lot of